# Is it reasonable to ask for the same time-regularity of the high and low dimensional signals?

Tags: math, autoencoders, latent-variable

Consider we are dealing with sequential data sampled from a continuous time signal $x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, so that the dataset will look like $\{x_0,x_1,…,x_n\}$, with $x_i= x(t_i)$.
Assume that we aim to perform dimensionality reduction of such sequence via an autoencoder, s.t we learn a low dimensional representation $z(t)\in \mathbb{R}^m$ , with $m\ll n$. In such settings, is it reasonable to ask for the same time-regularity of the high and low dimensional signals? (e.g. does $x \in C^0 \Rightarrow z \in C^0$?)

Papers or any kind of resource touching such problem is appreciated!